# why my MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS did not call

Tags: android

i have a problem with my one of the feature onTouchlistener.
here is my code.

```
private float mPrevX;
private float mPrevY;
private static final String TAG = "moveAbleButton";
public MainActivity mainActivity;
public moveAbleButton(MainActivity mainActivity1)
{
    mainActivity=mainActivity1;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    float currX,currY;

    if (motionEvent.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS)
    {

        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS");
        Intent i = new Intent(mainActivity, newActivity.class);
        mainActivity.startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }

    else if(motionEvent.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {

        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch:ACTION_DOWN ");
        mPrevX = motionEvent.getX();
        mPrevY = motionEvent.getY();
        return true;
    }

    else if (motionEvent.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {

        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: ACTION_MOVE");
        currX = motionEvent.getRawX();
        currY = motionEvent.getRawY();
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());
        marginParams.setMargins((int)(currX - mPrevX), (int)(currY - mPrevY),0, 0);
        android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

as you can see i want to move my button anywhere on the screen(it works fine) but i also wan to when i press the button my new activity also called. but motionEvent.Action_Button_press **never call**. **i also have grid view with three column in my activity** sorry for poor English and thanks in advance.

and in my main activity

```
 Button fab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    moveAbleButton buttonMove = new moveAbleButton(this);

    fab.setOnTouchListener(buttonMove);
```

Comment: [`MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS) -- Added in API level 23 -- This action is not a touch event so it is delivered to `onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent)` rather than `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`.

Comment: some code example please ?

Comment: i add ffab.setOnGenericMotionListener(buttonMove); in my code also implements view.OnGenericMotionListener in my class but not working.

Comment: Just use `onTouch()`. Add a `case` for `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, and if the x,y hasn't changed more than a small amount, treat it like a click, and start your `Activity`. An `OnGenericMotionListener` will fail anyway on devices with API<23.

Comment: Still i can't get the actual output that i want i can move the button but when i release the button it open a new activity. i want to move button but when i click on it then it will open new activity.

Comment: You need to compare the x,y in the `ACTION_UP` event to the x,y in the `ACTION_DOWN` event; i.e., figure the distance. If it's greater than what you want the "slop" to be for a click, then don't start the `Activity`.

Comment: thanks Mike M. its work for me.